# Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. on SQL with c# windows application

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, sql-server-2008

I am using C# Windows application for trying to download 700 MB to 2GB video file from SQL server using C# windows application. before this I have error (Connection time out) during upload file I have resolved that with extend connection time with 30 seconds on SSMS.

Now I get this message:

[image]

The code I'm using:

```
private void OpenFile(string id)
    {
        using (SqlConnection cn = GetConnection())
        {
            string query = "select * from CHATVIDEO where ID=@id";
            
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = id;
            cn.Open();
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                var name = reader["VDONAME"].ToString();
                var data = (byte[])reader["PATHLINK"];
                var extn = reader["Extension"].ToString();
                var dtimes = reader["SentDateTime"].ToString();

                var newfile = path + name.Replace(extn, id + dtimes) + extn;
                File.WriteAllBytes(newfile, data);
                //System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(newfile);
                newerfile = newfile.ToString();
            }
            cn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is your application x64?

Comment: If you define your SqlCommand behavior as `SequentialAccess`, you can read the array in chunks and save it to, e.g., a FileStream (which provides async methods, so you can more easily show a progress of the operation and also cancel it, in case it's requested / necessary).

Comment: Read and write the data in streaming mode, not the entire file at one step. This will reduce memory consumption. No need to download all and then write all because you do nothing with this data inbetween

Comment: @mu88 my application is x86 based

Comment: I read this message only on downloading file above 600MB.

Comment: Why are you trying to store a 600MB file in the database? Even if there's a good reason to do this, you should *not* try to read the entire file as a 600MB-sized `byte[]` array in memory. You wouldn't do that with a local file after all. You'd use a stream to read the data in chunks. Storing 600MB in the database as just a `varbinary(max)` causes performance issues too. The server will retrieve the entire 600MB blob in memory even if you wanted to read just 500 bytes in the middle, or read the file in chunks

Comment: Data like that should be stored as [FILESTREAM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filestream-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) data. Such data is stored outside the database and can be [retrieved and handled as a stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sqlclient-streaming-support) with `reader.GetStream()`

Comment: You can obtain [`Stream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream?view=net-5.0&viewFallbackFrom=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) object with [`GetStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstream?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) method. The same is for file: get `FileStream` with `File.Open(path, 2, 2)` and then use [`CopyTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copyto?view=net-5.0#System_IO_Stream_CopyTo_System_IO_Stream_System_Int32_) method on DB stream.